# Keras CNN model gives no gradients error during training

Tags: neural-network, keras, training, image-preprocessing, convolutional-neural-network

I’m trying to create a Convolutional Neural Network model, using an 824 image dataset, for predicting an output value. Problem is that the dataset is quite unstructured, as there are plenty of RGB and grayscale images, and there are no subfolders inside.

I changed them all to grayscale and created train/validation/test splits with the resized images. Then I made a Keras CNN model, but when I try to use fit_generator I have a No gradients provided Value error.

I've attached the colab code. As I’m new in the field of Deep Learning, I would appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

```
base_dir = '/content/drive/My Drive/Colab/chondro d2 23112016'
tif_img = glob.glob("/content/drive/My Drive/Colab/chondro d2 23112016/*.TIF")

#Create train/test/validation directories
train_dir = os.path.join(base_dir,'train')
#os.mkdir(train_dir)

validation_dir = os.path.join(base_dir,'validation')
#os.mkdir(validation_dir)

test_dir = os.path.join(base_dir,'test')
#os.mkdir(test_dir)

base_dir = '/content/drive/My Drive/Colab/chondro d2 23112016'
tif_img = glob.glob("/content/drive/My Drive/Colab/chondro d2 23112016/*.TIF")
train_dir = os.path.join(base_dir,'train')

# Images to the folders
# TRAIN
filelist = glob.glob(os.path.join(train_dir, "*.TIF"))
for f in filelist:
    os.remove(f)

fnames = [os.path.basename(os.path.normpath(tif_img[i])) for i in range(400)]
for fname in fnames:
  src = os.path.join(base_dir,fname)
  dst = os.path.join(train_dir,fname)
  shutil.copyfile(src,dst)
# grayscale and resize to (224,224)
for i in range(len(os.listdir(train_dir))):
  im = Image.open(train_dir + '/'+ os.listdir(train_dir)[i]).convert('L')
  new_im = im.resize((224,224))
  new_im.save(train_dir + '/'+ os.listdir(train_dir)[i])

# VALIDATION
filelist = glob.glob(os.path.join(validation_dir, "*.TIF"))
for f in filelist:
    os.remove(f)

fnames = [os.path.basename(os.path.normpath(tif_img[i])) for i in range(400,600)]
for fname in fnames:
  src = os.path.join(base_dir,fname)
  dst = os.path.join(validation_dir,fname)
  shutil.copyfile(src,dst)

for i in range(len(os.listdir(validation_dir))):
  im = Image.open(validation_dir + '/'+ os.listdir(validation_dir)[i]).convert('L')
  new_im = im.resize((224,224))
  new_im.save(validation_dir + '/'+ os.listdir(validation_dir)[i])

# TEST
filelist = glob.glob(os.path.join(test_dir, "*.TIF"))
for f in filelist:
    os.remove(f)

fnames = [os.path.basename(os.path.normpath(tif_img[i])) for i in range(600,824)]
for fname in fnames:
  src = os.path.join(base_dir,fname)
  dst = os.path.join(test_dir,fname)
  shutil.copyfile(src,dst)

for i in range(len(os.listdir(test_dir))):
  im = Image.open(test_dir + '/'+ os.listdir(test_dir)[i]).convert('L')
  new_im = im.resize((224,224))
  new_im.save(test_dir + '/'+ os.listdir(test_dir)[i])

# Convolutional Model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape = (224, 224, 1)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(256,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1))

model.compile(loss='mse',
              optimizer='rmsprop',
              metrics=['mse','mae'])

# Data Augmentation
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        rotation_range=40,
        width_shift_range=0.2,
        height_shift_range=0.2,
        rescale=1./255,
        shear_range=0.2,
        zoom_range=0.2,
        horizontal_flip=True,
        fill_mode='nearest')

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)

datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        rotation_range=40,
        width_shift_range=0.2,
        height_shift_range=0.2,
        rescale=1./255,
        shear_range=0.2,
        zoom_range=0.2,
        horizontal_flip=True,
        fill_mode='nearest')

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(base_dir,target_size=(224,224),batch_size=20,class_mode=None, classes = ['train'])

validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(base_dir,target_size=(224,224),batch_size=20,class_mode=None, classes = ['validation'])

history = model.fit_generator(train_generator,steps_per_epoch=100,epochs=30,validation_data=validation_generator,validation_steps=50)

---------------------------------------------------
ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable
```

Comment: You are using `base_dir` in both `train_datagen.flow_from_directory` and `test_datagen.flow_from_directory`. Is this correct? I am asking because earlier in your code you are restructuring your dataset and moving files from `base_dir` to `train_dir`, `test_dir`, and `validation_dir`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I wasn't sure about that too. But it seems that it was the only way to read the images, as the `flow_from_directory` requires a structure with subfolders. When I tried to use `train_dir` and `test_dir`, I had a `Found 0 images belonging to 0 classes.`